# com.google.android.apps.gsa.sidekick.main.h.n: Could not complete scheduled request to refresh entries. ClientErrorCode: 1

Tags: java

I was working with search fragment, where l can folllow and get users,to add my friend list,

but after l did, l still getting error.

please help

```
search_line = view.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);

    myusers = new ArrayList<>();

    userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), myusers);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);

    readUsers();
    search_line.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            searchUsers(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });



    return view;

}



private void searchUsers(String m){

    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").orderByChild("usersname").startAt(m)
            .endAt(m+"\f8ff");

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            myusers.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                myusers.add(user);
            }

            userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}






 private void readUsers(){

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (search_line.getText().toString().equals("")){

                    myusers.clear();

                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                        User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        myusers.add(user);

                    }

                    userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

xml:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/SearchBtn"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground">


<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    android:id="@+id/SearchToolbar">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_searchbutton"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/search_bar"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:hint="Search a friend to Follow"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/SearchBtn"
    android:id="@+id/recyleview"/>
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: error: resource drawable/bck2 (aka com.Jannah.way.mustaqiin:drawable/bck2) not found.